# MSBuild (for Delphi) Make-like functionality

Tags: delphi, msbuild

I am trying to set up dependencies for a set of Delphi packages, such at if Application A uses Package 1 and Package 2, and Application B uses Package 1 only, then only Application A is rebuilt when Package 2 is changed. 
At the moment, I am using a Group File, and each Package and Application is built (re-linked), even if it or one of it's dependencies is not changed.

UPDATE:

`Unit1.pas` is in `Package 1`

`Unit2.pas` is in `Package 2`

`Application A` uses `Package 1` and `Package 2`

`Application B` use `Package 2`

What I want is that if I change `Unit1.pas`, then *ONLY* `Package 1` and `Application B` is rebuilt. `make` will do this, but I can't work out how MSBUILD could be made to work.

My worked example uses a group file, which might be the underlying problem.

Comment: You'll need to be a little more specific about what you are trying to accomplish. Are you trying this in the IDE or running MSBuild from the command line? A "compile" always relinks, even if nothing changed, but it only rebuilds dcus that are out of date. A "build" rebuilds any dcu that it has the source for. You can setup dependencies in the IDE (right click on a project and choose Dependenices) or you can create your own MSBuild file and control the dependencies.

Comment: I have add example to (hopefully) clarify the situation

Comment: Exe's or bpl's will always be relinked. You can speed up the compile time by using make like: msbuild /target:Make YourGroupProject.groupproj. This will only recompile (build new dcus) for any files that changed and their dependencies, but the final output files will still be relinked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I have sorted this out. Groupprojs will always rebuild / relink, so that is not what I want.

I have created a targets file, such that it defines the 4 projects and the dependencies of each. It has to be all the dependencies, both code and binary (i.e. the packages).

Msbuild has an attribute 'DependsOnTarget', but this doesn't achieve what I want, so I have added dependencies on both the code and packages. The final build.targets file looks like this ...

```
<Project ToolsVersion="3.5" 
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
     DefaultTargets="Default">

<ItemGroup>
    <Package1 Include=".\Package1\Package1.dproj"/>
    <Package2 Include=".\Package2\Package2.dproj"/>
    <App6 Include=".\App6\Project6.dproj"/>
    <App7 Include=".\App7\Project7.dproj"/>
</ItemGroup>    

<ItemGroup>
    <Package1ExternalSourceFiles Include=".\Package1\*.pas" />
    <Package2ExternalSourceFiles Include=".\Package2\*.pas" />
    <App6ExternalSourceFiles Include=".\App6\*.pas" />
    <App7ExternalSourceFiles Include=".\App7\*.pas" />

    <Package1BinaryFiles Include=".\Package1\Win32\Release\Package1.bpl" />
    <Package2BinaryFiles Include=".\Package2\Win32\Release\Package2.bpl" />
    <App6BinaryFiles Include=".\App6\bin\Project6.exe" />
    <App7BinaryFiles Include=".\App7\bin\Project7.exe" />       
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="App6" Inputs="@(App6ExternalSourceFiles);@(Package1BinaryFiles);@(Package2BinaryFiles)" Outputs="@(App6BinaryFiles)" DependsOnTargets="Package1;Package2">
<Message Text="App6" /> 
<MSBuild Projects="@(App6)"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="App7" Inputs="@(App7ExternalSourceFiles);@(Package1BinaryFiles)" Outputs="@(App7BinaryFiles)" DependsOnTargets="Package1">
<Message Text="App7" /> 
<MSBuild Projects="@(App7)"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="Package1" Inputs="@(Package1ExternalSourceFiles)" Outputs="@(Package1BinaryFiles)">
<Message Text="Package1" /> 
<MSBuild Projects="@(Package1)"/>
</Target>       

<Target Name="Package2" Inputs="@(Package2ExternalSourceFiles)" Outputs="@(Package2BinaryFiles)">
<Message Text="Package2" /> 
<MSBuild Projects="@(Package2)"/>
</Target>

<Target Name="Build">
    <CallTarget Targets="Package1;Package2;App6;App7"/>
</Target>
</Project>
```

Whether this is scalable I am not sure, we could potentially have a large number of projects and dependencies.

UPDATE: Actually the binary dependency on the Applications isn't needed, if they are shipped separate from the packages. Recompiling Package 1, without changing it's interface would mean that App6 and App7 are not rebuilt.